# Adding a legend to these two histograms in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I find R and ggplot to be extremely unintuitive. So any guidance would be appreciated. I have already tried putting the two vectors I want to make histograms from into a data frame, but I could never get the alpha value of each histogram to be different.

So now I use the code:

```
ggplot(mydata) + geom_histogram(aes(x=mydata$D2prediction75At,y = ..density..,color = "blue"),color="darkblue", fill="blue",bins=41, alpha=0.75) 
 + geom_histogram(aes(x=mydata$D2y,y = ..density..,color = "red"),color="darkblue", fill="red",bins=41, alpha=0.5)
```

and some other options, hopefully not relevant:

```
+ theme_pander() + ggtitle("Histograms") +xlab("Subjective Elicitations")+ylab("Density")+theme(  panel.border = element_blank(),  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

to produce:

[image]

All I want is to add a legend showing the red histogram represents data A and the blue represents data B.

This seems to be a very difficult task in R.

Comment: Try with removing `color="darkblue"` from both geoms. This should give you a legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try next approach, in addition of the good advice of **@GregorThomas**. First an example using `iris` dataset, you need to pass the `fill` option inside `aes()` and then use `scale_fill_manual()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Example
ggplot(iris)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=Sepal.Length,y = ..density..,color = "blue",fill='B'),
                 color="darkblue",bins=41, alpha=0.75)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=Sepal.Width,y = ..density..,color = "red",fill='A'),
                 color="darkblue",bins=41, alpha=0.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","red"),'Var')
```

Output:

[image]

In the case of your code, try this (not tested as no data was shared):

```
#Code OP
ggplot(mydata) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=D2prediction75At,y = ..density..,
                     color = "blue",fill='B'),
                 color="darkblue",bins=41, alpha=0.75) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=D2y,y = ..density..,color = "red",fill='A'),
                 color="darkblue",bins=41, alpha=0.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","red"),'Data')+
  theme_pander() + 
  ggtitle("Histograms") +
  xlab("Subjective Elicitations")+
  ylab("Density")+
  theme(  panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks this works! No idea what it is doing though...

Comment: @user434180 I will explain a bit. You had the fill values outside `aes()` that was not creating the legend. You can move the `fill` inside `aes()` and assign a name lets say A. That will create the legend. As no color for filling was defined, you will need to change that with `scale_fill_manual()` to reach the expected colors. Hope that is a bit clear for you!

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot` is designed to work with data in long format - in which case legends are produced automatically. I'd suggest converting your data into a format `ggplot` likes. You haven't shared any data, but based on your ggplot calls, this is my best guess. If you need help debugging, please share a reproducible sample of your data.

```
mydata_long = pivot_longer(mydata, cols = c(D2prediction75At, D2y))

ggplot(mydata_long, aes(x = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.65, bins = 41, color = "darkblue") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(D2prediction75At = "blue", D2y = "red") +
  ... # your other options
```

Comment: I tried this, and similar methods, but I could never get both histograms to validly be on a density scale. Either they were counts, or they were densities but on the scale of the first data series.

Comment: Yeah - if you need debugging help we'd need some sample data...

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
 mydata_long <- melt(mydata,  measure = c("D2prediction75At", "D2y"))
ggplot(mydata_long, aes(x = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.65, bins = 41, color = "darkblue") +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c(D2prediction75At = "blue", D2y = "red") +
   ... # your other options
```